# Flag a newly added subid within a ID

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe as below with thousands of ID's. It has a list of ID's which have sub id's within them as shown. The subid's may get changed on daily basis, either a new sub id may be added, or an existing sub id maybe lost.

I need to create 2 new columns, which will flag whenever a sub id is added/lost.

So, in the below format you can see that on the 12th, a new sub id 'D' is added 
and on the 13th, and existing sub id (c) is lost. 
i want to create a new column/flag to track these sub ids. Can you please help me with this?

I am using Python 3.5. Thanks

Sample format for one ID:

```
ID Sub Id     Date     is_new  
1    a     3/11/2016      0
1    b     3/11/2016      0
1    c     3/11/2016      0
1    a     3/12/2016      0
1    b     3/12/2016      0
1    c     3/12/2016      0
1    d     3/12/2016      1
1    a     3/13/2016      0
1    b     3/13/2016      0
1    d     3/13/2016      0
```

Comment: how can you mark sub id C on 3/13 if it already lost? Do you mark sub id D as added on 3/12?  What indicators will you use? 'A' for added and 'D' for deleted?

Comment: I can create another column called is_new or is_old to track these changes with values of 1/0.

Comment: please put your expected result in your sample data.

Comment: Hello. I have put in the expected result when a new sub id gets added.  But I am not quite sure how I can flag the id's that go missing (for eg: C goes missing from 3/13 onwards).

Comment: Does it help if you mark sub id c on 3/12 as deleted?

Comment: Yes that would be fine too. How would you do the is_new field?

Answer (score 0):

Below query will indicate when a sub-id is added or deleted. Hope this helps.

> - Get the max and min update date per id, I put it in a temp table name: min_max
> - If update date is same with min and max then mark them as 1
> - Lag and lead functions will get the previous and next sub id per ID, subid order by
> - Put everything on a subquery (table s)
> - If update date is not the start or end date per ID, then it can be added (is_mindte=0) or deleted (is_maxdte=0)
> - If is_added column is null, then it is added on that date (is_added is null); If is_deleted column is null, then it is deleted the next update date (is_added is null)

```
    select s.id,
       s.subid,
       s.upddate,
(case when is_mindte=0 and is_added is null 
      then 1 else 0 end ) is_new,
(case when is_maxdte=0 and is_deleted is null 
      then 1 else 0 end) is_removed
from (
   with min_max as
      (select   id,min(upddate) mindate,max(upddate) maxdate
       from     myTable
       group by id)
  select t.id,
         t.subid,
         t.upddate,
         case when t.upddate=m.mindate 
              then 1 else 0 end is_mindte,
         case when t.upddate=m.maxdate 
              then 1 else 0 end is_maxdte,
         lag(t.subid) over (partition by t.id, t.subid order by t.upddate) is_added,
         lead(t.subid) over (partition by t.id, t.subid order by t.upddate) is_deleted 
   from  myTable t, min_max m
   where t.id=m.id) s
order by s.id, 
      s.upddate, 
      s.subid

sample result:
ID  SUBID   UPDDATE         IS_NEW  IS_REMOVED
1   a   2016-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   0
1   b   2016-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   0
1   c   2016-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   0
1   a   2016-03-12T00:00:00Z    0   0
1   b   2016-03-12T00:00:00Z    0   0
1   c   2016-03-12T00:00:00Z    0   1
1   d   2016-03-12T00:00:00Z    1   0
1   a   2016-03-13T00:00:00Z    0   0
1   b   2016-03-13T00:00:00Z    0   0
1   d   2016-03-13T00:00:00Z    0   0
2   a   2016-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   0
2   b   2016-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   0
2   c   2016-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   0
```

Comment: Thanks, I added another row    1 e 03/14/2016 00:00:00.. with e as the new sub id on the 14th.. It was not able to track that.. the is_new says 0 for that instead of 1. Can you please check that.. Also, can this be done in an easier way using pandas?

Comment: I assumed you want it in oracle since you tag it as oracle. By the way, i fixed the code and it should be "is_mindte=0 and is_added is null"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. I had mentioned this in my initial email "I am using Python 3.5.".. i can use the sql query in and create a pandas dataframe using sqlalchemy. Was just wondering if it can be done in a simpler way using pandas. It would be great if you could help me with the script in pandas. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: if you are pleased with my answer (partially in oracle), please up vote my solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you would do this in Pandas? When a subid gets removed, I would like it to have a additional row, with the is_removed column = 1 on the date it is actually removed. Thanks